# Symfony2 ajax requests with json

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, symfony

I have set up an article bundle with posts in Symfony2, everything is working good, but I'm trying to use AJAX and Json to navigate through posts, the iterance I want is this one:

```
Index page loads random post (this is done without ajax)
There are two buttons, previous and next. (this is working without ajax, controller gets postId and do +-1 to navigate through DB)
```

I actually have no clue on how to use AJAX and JSON to do the iterance dinamycaly without refreshing the page, get on my controller JSON data and parse to my twig template...

This is my twig template...

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %} {% block container %}
<div class="flecha flecha-left">{{ icon('chevron-left') }}</div>
<div class="flecha flecha-right">{{ icon('chevron-right') }}</div>
<div id="dilema" class="row">
    <div id="dilor"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 column">
        <div class="choice bluechoice">
            <div class="opcion">{{ decision.opcionAzul }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 column">
        <div class="choice redchoice">
            <div class="opcion">{{ decision.opcionRoja }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 column">
        <p>{{ icon('stats') }} {{ decision.votosAzul + decision.votosRoja }}
            votos</p>
        <p>{{ icon('calendar') }} {{ decision.createdAt|date }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 column">
        <p>{{ icon('bullhorn')}} {{ decision.descripcion }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock container %} {% block left_column %} Comment count:
<div id="fos_comment_thread" data-thread="{{ thread.id }}">{% include
    'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:comments.html.twig' with { 'comments': comments,
    'thread': thread } %}</div>
{% block javascript %} {% javascripts
'@FOSCommentBundle/Resources/assets/js/comments.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %} {% endblock javascript %} {% endblock left_column %}
{% block javas %}

{% endblock javas %}
```

So the point is clicking on the `div#flecha` icons and navigate with Ajax, get JSON data for the next or previous ID, and replace the `{{ decision }}` options (this is my Entity results) with the new JSON data retrieved... Also, as you can see I'm using FOSCommentBundle but this can be handled via Controller, in where I set the comment thread_id to be the current entity ID...

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: Your twig - template will get parsed only at a page refresh.
It's at the server side execution environment.
But you could retrieve the complete request via ajax though (as html),
and then replace nodes on your page via the JS DOM API (which I would not recommend).
If you just want to display the JSON - Data, you will also have to manipulate the DOM - tree via JS for yourself, but that is more or less how partial page rendering is done.
There was an approach early with the <esi ... > tags, but they haven't made it to the HTML - Standard, though supported by Varnish.

Comment: Yeah that's the theory... But how can I do that? That's what I don't know, in pure PHP+HTML I know how to do, but not with Symfony2 methods and stuff...

Comment: This is a question related to implementing techniques of partial page rendering and not Symfony2 specific.

Comment: Simplest form: class HelloController
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
/**Simplest form of retrieving JSON**/
class HelloController
{
   public function indexAction($name)
   { 
      $response = new Response();
      $response->setContent(json_encode(array(
      'data' => 123,
      )));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

---

jQuery Ajax:
var response = $.ajax( { url : http://your.host/hello.php };
---- DOM with jQuery:
var dilema = $('#dilema'); // find dom node
dilema.html(''); // clear inner html
Var div = $(''); // create new one
dilema.append(div); // insert it into the dom tree.

Comment: But like I said: "div#flecha icons and navigate with Ajax, get JSON data for the next or previous ID, and replace the {{ decision }} options (this is my Entity results) with the new JSON " sounds as if you are missing out the point that the twig template is never deployed to the client. A client (webbrowser e.g.) only retrieves a valid HTML - Document which contains the rendered twig template.